# when posting PHP the PHP changes the variable by loosing the underscore

Tags: php

I am sending a string with php email in php script where the body is something like

```
   "http://www.landing1.co.za/landing.php?id=12&user_name=admin"
```

but every second or third one comes through as

```
   http://www.landing1.co.za/landing.php?id=12&username=admin"
```

losing the underscore that makes the link incorrect.

so when a person follows the link the data is blank because user_name is not correct and coming through as username.

Please help

Comment: PHP won't be doing that by itself, and without a lot more information, there's no way we can help you work out what is causing it.

Comment: I would suggest searching your code for the string `username` - somewhere you may just have a faulty link. PHP does exactly as its told, so if it is missing an underscore it's because it is being instructed to.

Comment: it sounds like an application error. Try to check your code for username, may be you've left it somewhere on your code.

Answer (score 0):

So there isn't anything in PHP that would do that. It sounds like you have `username` somewhere in your code. Do a search in your whole codebase for `username` and you may find your problem.  If you want to do a hacky workaround you could add this in your code:

```
if (!isset($_GET['user_name']) && isset($_GET['username'])) {
    $_GET['user_name'] = $_GET['username'];
}
```